# Healpy mask has border

Tags: python, healpy

I am trying to mask my healpy map for pixels that have no data, however when I apply the healpy mask with `badval=-1.6375e+30`, there seems to be a border around my mask.

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np

# load the mask
mask = hp.read_map('mask_nvss_S20-S1000_Ns64.fits')

# degrade the mask to NSIDE = 16
mask16 = np.round(hp.ud_grade(mask, 16))

# apply it to the map
masked_map = hp.ma(map1)
masked_map.mask = np.logical_not(mask16)

# masked map
nvss_map = np.round(masked_map)
```

Can anyone help me remove this border effect?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that you're using?

Comment: ```# load the mask
```mask = hp.read_map('mask_nvss_S20-S1000_Ns64.fits')#.astype(np.bool)```

```# degrade the mask to NSIDE = 16```
```mask16 = np.round(hp.ud_grade(mask, 16))```

```# apply it to the map```
```masked_map = hp.ma(map1)```

```masked_map.mask = np.logical_not(mask16)```

```# masked map```
```nvss_map = np.round(masked_map)```

Comment: Could you also upload the data somewhere? I have an idea, but can't check that without the original data.

Comment: Here's a link to the data  https://files.fm/u/py9v552q

Comment: That's the map at nside=16, we'd need to have the nside=64 map to reproduce the analysis.

Comment: @DanielLenz, what do you think could be causing this effect, even at Nside = 64, it is still visible

Comment: Here is a link to the nside = 64 data https://files.fm/u/s65se6c5

Comment: The mask that you're reading (`mask_nvss_S20-S1000_Ns64.fits`) already has the issue that you describe. Without access to the original data and your code to processes that, we won' be able to reproduce that or help you. Moreover, what is `map1` in your analysis? That's never defined.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have a full picture of the problem, but I assume your problem is related to the downgrading of the mask.

When going from a high-resolution boolean mask to a lower resolution, there are three different strategies you can follow. The choice depends on your problem.

I'll illustrate the effect with the mask that you have provided, showing a zoom-in:

[image]

#### Downgrading a mask with bool type

You can simply downgrade the *boolean* mask, giving you the left panel in the figure below. Note that small patches will turn out unmasked in this procedure.

```
map_lowres_bool = hp.ud_grade(mask_highres.astype(bool), nside=16)
```

#### Downgrading a mask with float type

If you instead downgrade your mask of type `float`, you'll get a continuous map with weights instead (middle panel below). I assume this produces the effect you're seeing.

```
map_lowres_float = hp.ud_grade(mask_highres.astype(float), nside=16)
```

#### Properly downgrading a mask with bool type

You can also downgrade a boolean mask such that all masked regions remain masked. Due to the lower resolution, your masked patches will be larger than in the original mask.

```
mask_lowres_proper = hp.ud_grade(mask.astype(float), nside=16).astype(float)
mask_lowres_proper = np.where(mask_lowres_proper == 1., True, False).astype(bool)
```

This produces the right panel below.

Hope you found this helpful, let me know if you have questions!

[image]